# SQL Server: Show a list of Customers that have more Orders than a specify Customer

Tags: sql-server

Yop guys, I have this little question to solve; I have 2 tables [Customers] and [Orders] who are linked by CustomerID. It's easy to get the COUNT() of Orders by each Customers...

```
SELECT c.CompanyName, COUNT(*) AS [Nbr of Orders]
FROM [Orders] o
INNER JOIN [Customers] c
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CompanyName
```

But the problem come from the last part of the question: I need to get that list but only those that have more Orders than one of those Customers (c.CompagnyName = 'XYZ')
I tried to add something like this WHERE clause

```
WHERE COUNT(*) > (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM [Orders] o
                  INNER JOIN [Customers] c
                  ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
                  WHERE c.CompagnyName = 'XYZ')
```

SQL Error :P

Look like ridiculous I know but if someone can tell me what I miss on !

Comment: Try putting brackets around your evaluating statement (count(*) > (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM [Orders] o
                  INNER JOIN [Customers] c
                  ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
                  WHERE c.CompagnyName = 'XYZ'))

Comment: I think you want a HAVING clause rather than a WHERE clause, as you are filtering on an aggregated function.

Comment: thanks @TheDumbRadish , I only changed WHERE for HAVING and work great !!! Arff, I can't thumb a comment :/

Comment: Have added it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can use a having clause.  So your example would be
    `SELECT c.CompanyName, COUNT(*) AS [Nbr of Orders]
    FROM [Orders] o
    INNER JOIN [Customers] c
    ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    GROUP BY c.CompanyName
    having count(*) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a HAVING clause rather than a WHERE clause, as you are filtering on an aggregated function